# Server on an android device

Tags: android

I'm creating an android app that should communicate with a PC application.
At first, I wrote the PC application as the server side of the connection (on Python),
but for some reasons I want to change it and to make the android app to the server side.

My problem is that the connection should be over the internet.
As I know, the android device (phone) is inside a private network of the cellular company,
which makes a problem to access the device over the internet.

Is there any way that the android device will be accessed directly from the internet?

Comment: with wifi or 3g(mobile internet....)

Comment: Server in phone over mobile network is a headache, mainly because the phone will be changing IP address all the time. What are the reasons to want server in phone?

Comment: I don't want to set up a server on the PC  - I want to avoid the complications of opening a port on the home router.

I need to create a connection between the mobile device and a PC  but I don't want the the user of the application will need to set his router configurations, If there is another way except running a server over mobile network on the mobile device I will be happy to hear about..

Comment: Typically to do this between a mobile network and a residential network you will have to use a server on the public internet as an intermediary and make both the phone and the PC be "clients".

Comment: over wifi try socket programing

Comment: Chris, is there a free service that you can recomend to use for setting up the server on the public internet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. IF you have access to TCP/UDP ports (they are not blocked on your private domain), 
give a shot to Java Socket Programming.

Whether the server is mobile or PC is totally up to you.

If you need to learn about socket programming, the best place to start is [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) on official Oracle documentation website.

[This](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077322/core-java/sockets-programming-in-java-a-tutorial.html) is yet another learning by example tutorial.

Comment: But thd problem with a server on the mobile device is that it can't be access from the public internet, is'nt it? The mobile device doesn't have a public IP... abd of course I can't change the configurations of the main router of the cellular company. Maybe there is a way to register there live?

Comment: Isn't your client on the same domain?

Comment: No, I'm trying to do this over 3g.